TV Mount outlet problem
I bought a TV mount to allow us to lower the TV, but the outlet is in the way. Currently with the height of the outlet, the TV would be scraping the ceiling (if it fit at all).
I don't have the money to pay an electrician to relocate the outlet and am not comfortable moving it myself. My partner has suggested that we secure 2x4s vertically to the studs and attach the mount to those, effectively creating a gap between the mount and the wall, and therefore not being impeded by the plug.
Is this something that could work? For reference the TV is 60", and about 40lbs. The mount is quite heavy itself. The wall is drywall with wooden studs.

There are all kinds of solutions for this. Non flush brackets.  Extension cords with flat plugs.  Recessed outlets.   You shouldn't need to build one out of sticks.  A picture would help, you can add one to the question

As noted in a comment, there are many ways to fix this - different type of mount, offset (as described in the question), replace the receptacle with a recessed receptacle, etc.
But yes, one way to do this that is (a) safe (both structurally and electrically and (b) does not require an electrician to install (note that in many places, provided you are not renting, you can do your own basic electrical work, but many people don't feel comfortable doing that and there is a learning curve involved) is to offset using wood.
You can use 2x4s installed in front of the existing studs (which are likely 2x4s, but with drywall in between the old and the new). That will give you an extra 1.5" of clearance if you install the 2x4s with the larger side flat against the wall, roughly centered over the studs. Use screws around 3" long (1.5" new 2x4s, 0.5" drywall, 1" into the studs). A typical "right angle" extension cord should fit within a 1.5" gap without a problem.
